# Python storing and plotting data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to categorize a csv data with 600000 rows and 2 columns into a few types of data. Is there any possible way that I could apply something like array in C so that I could use `ply.scatter(x,y)` , where x and y correspond to columns of each type, to plot them out?

The way I am currently using is to store them into different files and then open it with `plt(float(row[0]), float(row[1]))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check csv package in python standard library:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

my sketched answer will be like

```py
import csv
x, y = [], []

with open('your.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        x.append(row[0])
        y.append(row[1])
```

Comment: Thanks. I have used the csv package to read the data, just not knowing how to use array in python. Your answer give a good answer to my array part of the question.

Comment: x,y =[], [] is list, mutable. To be immutable array, you could consider numpy.array. ax = numpy.array(x)

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas, with `x` and `y` two different columns, and then use `df.plot.scatter(...)` as documented [here.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html)